# gensym in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I know gensym can generate symbols, but it seems that there is a global counter there with the base, which can be very large, for example, `(define s (gensym 's))` the s can end up with `s12345`.
I am wondering whether there is a way to reset the counter, where the number generated can be small?like `s14`?

Answer (score 11):

There's no way to do that, otherwise it would have been mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._gensym%29%29).  You can only provide a "base" for the new symbol.  If you really need a small counter, then it's easy to make up your own `gensym` using [`string->unreadable-symbol`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/symbols.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-~3euninterned-symbol%29%29), for example:

```
(define gensym
  (let ([counter 0])
    (lambda ([x 'g])
      (if (number? x)
        (set! counter x)
        (begin0 (string->unreadable-symbol
                 (format "~a~a" x counter))
          (set! counter (add1 counter)))))))
```

Comment: NICE...That's a helpful little tool!!

Comment: what are its applications?